# switching from one camera to other in unity ,view entering from right

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two cameras in the same position.I want to switch from one camera to other (with a transition effect) such that second view replaces the first camera view entering from the left side moving inwards and filling the screen..                                                    Camera fading in and fading out effects are available in unity wiki..Can anyone suggest me a technique to achieve this effect..

Comment: first camera has a black background and second camera has a red background.So the red background will enter the view from left and fill in the screen...Both cameras being stationary

Comment: If you have additional information don't place it inside a comment, add it to the question itself so others will see it immediatelly

Answer (score 1):

You can try to animate [Camera.rect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html). Otherwise you will have to render both in a RenderTexture and combine rendered images in a small shader with a translate parameter changing from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

While i'm not really really sure of the application for the switching of the camera if you were to instantiate it dynamically you would be able to use lerp and other function calls to manipulate behavior and not need to use multiple cameras.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

As a side note i'm sure you could reverse engineer some camera effects similar to this one in order to achieve the background(a little confused about what you want to do with that)

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/script-CameraMotionBlur.html